# Python, how to pass arbitrary variables from function to function in the most elegant way?

Tags: python, function, parameters, keyword-argument

I have a dictionary `vars = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}` with key/value pairs. This dictionary can be extended with new variables in the future.
I would like to call func1 with variables from vars dict. In func1 I will use zero or more variables from vars dict.
If func1 has to call func2, I would like func2 to receive all variables from original vars dict.
Func2 will use zero or more variables from vars dict.

Something like this:

```
def func1(**kwargs):
    print(f'func1 a = {a}, b is not important')
    return func2(**kwargs)

def func2(**kwargs):
    return f'func2 a = {a}, b = {b}, both variables are important'


vars = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}
print(func1(**vars))
```

But this doesn't work because kwargs is a dictionary.
I can unpack variables at the beginning of the function if needed as:

```
a = kwargs['a']
b = kwargs['b']
```

but if a new variable "c" shows up in original vars dictionary, I will have to change these unpackings at the beginning of the each function.
I could also set parameters `def func1(a, b):` and `def func2(a, b):` but i have to recreate kwargs dict in order to send it further down. Again, if a new variable "c" shows up, I will have to change signature of each function.
I could also define func1 as bellow in order pass variable a further down:

```
def func1(a, kwargs):
    print(f'func1 a = {a}, b is not important')
    kwargs['a'] = a
    return func2(**kwargs)
```

Maybe to create an object and to set its properties as vars dict key/value pairs, and than send this object as function's parameter?

How to pass arbitrary variables from function to function in the most elegant way in this scenario?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just keep the variables in the dictionary and access them that way?

```
def func1(**kwargs):
    print(f"func1 a = {kwargs['a']}, b is not important")
    return func2(**kwargs)

def func2(**kwargs):
    return f"func2 a = {kwargs['a']}, b = {kwargs['b']}, both variables are important"


vars = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}
print(func1(**vars))
```

Comment: In that case, I don't need kwargs at all. I will send vars dict as a parameter to every function and than use vars['x'] for needed variable.
It could work.